# Structure a valid route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have the following routes inside my Rails.application.routes

```
get '/c/*name', :to => 'categories#show', :as => :filter_categories
get '/c/*name/*token', :to => 'categories#nest_products', :as => :nest_categories
```

and this controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    params[:name]
    @products, @filters = ProductFilterService.new(params[:name]).filter_by_taxon
    @selected_taxons = ProductFilterService.new(params[:name]).selected_taxons
  end

  def nest_products
    puts params[:token]
    render :show
  end
end
```

trying like this example localhost:3000/adidas/fH72VLNlAma2JWc, i want to excecute the method nest_products but always goes to method show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the declaration order of your routes like this, so it matches `nest_categories` first if you have a `token` param :

```
get '/c/*name/*token', :to => 'categories#nest_products', :as => :nest_categories
get '/c/*name', :to => 'categories#show', :as => :filter_categories
```

Because `localhost:3000/adidas/fH72VLNlAma2JWc` matches both routes, you need to declare the most specific first.